# How do I get a backlog of podcasts into a cloud-based stream for my iPhone?

Tags: ios, podcasts, cloud-storage

I have a large ~30Gb backlog of podcast episodes that I am slowly working my way through. Currently these are stored in iTunes and I occasionally sync an old iPod Classic to get new episodes and delete the episodes that I have listened to.

I would like to move to one of the iOS apps such as Instacast or Downcast so that I only have to carry a single device - my iPhone - around with me for my audio needs. I would like to be able to listen to the backlog of episodes as well as download new episodes, ideally in the same feeds. I am guessing that I would have to move my podcast backlog to cloud storage and set up some kind of feed to one of these apps, although I don't see this listed as a feature of either.

What is the most sensible way to achieve this?

Comment: What version of ios are you using? I think [iTunes in the cloud](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/) would do it for you, but I don't know if they aren't "purchased" you may need [iTunes match](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/) $$

Comment: From what I understand of any current potential solution involving iTunes match and iCloud is that it will be expensive and clunky, e.g. having to download podcasts through iTunes on my laptop and then pull them down a second time on my iPhone whilst paying for space for them to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

One method I could see is getting yourself a free web hosting account somewhere, I've used [Fav.CC](http://fav.cc/) and [3owl](http://3owl.com). Both of these would allow you to upload all of your podcasts, as well as run Podcast Generator.

Basically you need to install Podcast Generator, then upload all of your podcasts to the ./media/ folder, with no sub directories, then run the "FTP Feature". You could then point your iPhone towards the feed.xml and you'll be able to stream your casts!

If some of the episodes aren't recognized, it's because of periods other than the one before the file extension. You may or may not have issues with the order specifically in the feed, although if you can search with your client, then you should be fine

Comment: Would this solution allow new episodes to be downloaded automatically and stored on the server? Would Podcast Generator create a feed per podcast? Both of these would need to be part of the solution. I want to continue to see my podcasts as separate entities to each other.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it would. You upload the new audio files, then regenerate the feed (update the xml via a button)

Comment: And yes, you need an install of Podcast Generator for each podcast. By install, I mean a new copy of it. It's a standalone PHP script + directory structure. Just make one folder for each podcast and copy Podcast Generator into each of them before setting it up.